# StrPos always returns False?

Tags: php, search-engine, strpos

I've been working on a very basic search engine. It basically operates by checking if the word exists. If it does, it returns the link. I know most of you would suggest to create a database from phpMyAdmin but I don't remember the password to make the `mySql_Connect` command work.

Anyway here is the code:

```
<?php

session_start();

$searchInput = $_POST['search'];

var_dump($inputPage1);
var_dump($searchİnput);

$inputPage1 = $_SESSION['pOneText'];
$inputPage2 = isset($_SESSION['pTwoText']) ? $_SESSION['pTwoText'] : "";
$inputPage3 = isset($_SESSION['pThreeText']) ? $_SESSION['pThreeText'] : "";

if (strpos($inputPage1, $searchInput)) {
    echo "True";
} else {
    echo "False";
}

?>
```

When I search a word, any word from any page, weather it exists or not, it always returns false. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Maybe there's nothing in `$_SESSION['pOneText']` or your search term is empty, or there really isn't any match. You haven't really supplied enough information here. Also, you probably shouldn't make forgettting your password affect how you architect your system!

Comment: İm very sorry if i didn't supply you with enough information. Ask What more you need and i can tell you. About the search term, i can assure you i have searched terms that exist in the page and that i red such as "The".

Comment: please share the following outputs:
print_r($_POST);
print_r($_SESSION);

and another thing, strpos should be used like this,
strpos($haystack, $niddle)
that means, if you want to search abc from abcdef, you should write 
strpos('abcdef','abc')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the PHP [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php):

> *Warning:* This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function.

So the function returns the integer `0` since `$searchInput` starts at the first character of `$inputPage1`. Since it is inside an if condition, that expects a boolean, the integer is then converted to one. When converted to boolean, zero is equal to false so instead the else block is executed.

To fix it, you need to use the `!==` operator (the not equal equivalent of `===`):

```
if (strpos($inputPage1, $searchInput) !== false) {
    //...
```

Comment: İt still returns false, thank you for your effort though!!

Comment: Do a `var_dump` on `$inputPage1` and `$searchInput`. Then edit your question to contain the result. And did you notice my edit, changing to `!== false`?

Comment: @DouglasMaron An example of what?

Comment: Of what i should do with var_dump, i read the php.net suggestion but i don't understand!

Comment: Right before the if clause, add this code: `var_dump($inputPage1);` and `var_dump($searchInput);` It will echo the types and values of the variables. Then edit your question so you can see what the values are. And [read up on debugging PHP](http://www.phpknowhow.com/basics/basic-debugging/).

Comment: Ok, i'll test it and then do it.

Comment: İt sais : int(1)string(3)"The"False

Comment: Ok, so the `int(1)` is the first variable (`$inputPage1`?). It is an integer with the value `1`. `string(3)"The"` is the second variable (`$searchInput`?). It is a string of length 3 with the value `The`. `strpos` expects to get two strings. Checking if the number `1` contains the string `the` makes no sense.

Comment: @DouglasMaron And please update your question with that information. It will be useful to others trying to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

Try str**i**pos() to match case insensitive

Answer (score -1):

First print all items in $_POST and $_SESSION using

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
print_r($_SESSION);
```

and ensure that the search string really exist in the bigger string .
Also make sure that your are using "false" to compare :
i.e

```
$pos = strpos($biggerString,$seachString);

if($pos !== false)
{
     echo "Not found";
}
```